# Cannot use __filename as default value in class constructor when initiating from another file NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

Here is my issue: I want to use NodeJS's __filename as value of some property. When creating a new instance of that class from another file, the property filename gets __filename value of the file where the **class** was created, not __filename of the file where I created the instance.

In 'class.js':

```js
class MyClass {
   constructor(props) {
      this.filename = __filename;
   }
}
```

In 'init.js':

```js
let obj = new MyClass();
```

Here, obj.filename should be './init.js' but is './class.js'

How can I get __filename to be the filename of the file the instance is created in instead of the file where the class is defined?

Comment: You have to pass it: `new MyClass(__filename)`. There's no way to access the variable from the scope of your caller.

Comment: @Bergi That's sad :'( Thanks

Comment: Yes, it does answer my question! but it is a bit overengineered for my basic use.

Comment: It's not something i'd typically suggest using. You should rather consider choosing a different design, if somehow possible, that doesn't need this. However, if you really really have no other choice, i guess parsing stack trace as described there might work...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```js
class MyClass {
   constructor(props) {
      this.filename = process.mainModule.filename;
   }
}
```

Comment: `init.js` isn't my main module so this won't work. I have to specify the filename when creating the instance, as @Bergi stated.